# System.InvalidOperationException occurred in WebDriver.dll while doing automation testing in Firefox driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have updated the latest selenium webdriver (v 3.4.0) installed and have latest firefox driver(0.15.0). I have these installed in a project which I am working on by "Manage Nuget Packages" option. Suddenly all of my tests are failing as it is not able to interact with any of the elements on firefox browser. To state about my issue, when I try the below simple tests on a google website

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
var MyKeyWord = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
MyKeyWord.SendKeys("Gmail");
```

it is failing with below exception.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (IndexOutOfBounds)
```

I was searching on how to handle this problem and I found a solution as below:
     driver = new FirefoxDriver(DRIVER_PATH);

But all my tests were executing without specifying these path in firefox earlier as firefox picks them when we install the required package using "Manage Nuget Packages" option. I am not sure why it started failing all of a sudden. Does someone have any suggestion on this?

Comment: What happens if you use geckodriver 0.16?

Comment: I haven't used it. I am checking about it. Just to get an idea, is it something like a driver file?

Answer (score 0):

Download latest geckodriver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. Unzip it and put gecodriver file your system path. Restart (if needed) .

This link will help for setup :  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Chromedriver displays in NuGet manager - one driver for Chrome and other one is Selenium Google Chrome driver. You have to install both, then it works.